# Cannot sign in to VNCServer with Home subscription on CentOS 7

Tags: centos-7, vncserver, realvnc

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to sign in with my RealVNC account on Linux. Whenever I execute `vncserver` it prompts me to run `vnclicense` to license the program, but I do not have an enterprise license as my account has the home plan, which does not utilize license keys. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have access to the GUI desktop on Linux and use the Licensing option from the VNC Server icon. If the icon isn't there, try running vnclicensewiz instead

Comment: I've tried running vnclicensewiz and signing in, but even after doing so when running vncserver it complains about not having a license. I'll see what else I can do.

Comment: That command is for Virtual Mode. Try sudo systemctl enable vncserver-x11-serviced --now    then sign in to VNC Viewer and use the team